# What's the standard way to create custom conversion between types in Rust?

Tags: type-conversion, rust

If I defined some enum and wanted to create a parser from string to that type, is there something better than just:

```
impl TheType {
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> TheType { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way for converting from a string / parsing text is to implement the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait. For the example from the question it would look like this:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

enum Failure {
    ReasonOne,
    ReasonTwo,
}

impl FromStr for TheType {
    type Err = Failure;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<TheType, Self::Err> { 
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For generic conversion that cannot fail, you should implement the [`std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait:

```
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum MyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Many(i64),
}

impl From<i64> for MyEnum {
    fn from(val: i64) -> Self {
        match val {
            1 => MyEnum::One,
            2 => MyEnum::Two,
            _ => MyEnum::Many(val),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(MyEnum::from(1), MyEnum::One);
    assert_eq!(MyEnum::from(2), MyEnum::Two);
    assert_eq!(MyEnum::from(3), MyEnum::Many(3));
}
```

Conveniently, implementing `From` also automatically implements [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html):

```
let one: MyEnum = 1.into(); assert_eq!(one, MyEnum::One);
let two: MyEnum = 2.into(); assert_eq!(two, MyEnum::Two);
let many: MyEnum = 3.into(); assert_eq!(many, MyEnum::Many(3));
```

For potentially failing conversion, you should implement [`std::convert::TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) instead. It's only available in Rust 1.34 and up though, before these versions you can use the implementation in the [`conv` crate](https://docs.rs/conv/*/conv/trait.TryFrom.html).